# Dimensions[] not working with assumptions?

Tags: matrix, symbolic, assumptions

I am trying to perform some symbolic calculus with tensors and matrices. I have recently noticed that one can set assumptions on variables by using the command `$Assumptions$` as described [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Matrices.html). However, when I make

```
$Assumptions$ = U ∈ Matrices[{d, m}, Reals];
$Assumptions$ = P ∈ Matrices[{d, t}, Reals];


Y = Transpose[U].P;
Dimensions[Y]
```

I get

> (* {2} *)

Using `TensorDimensions` doesn't return a useful result either, as

```
TensorDimensions[Y]
```

> (* TensorDimensions[Transpose[U].Phi] *)

If I am assuming $U$ to be a $d\times m$ matrix and $P$ to be a $d\times t$ matrix, then the product between $U^{\intercal}P$ should be an $m\times t$ matrix. I am sure I am probably misunderstanding either the usage of `$Assumptions$` or the usage of the command `Dimensions[]` regarding this particular case. But if that is so, why is it not working this way?

Comment: You have syntax errors: it's `$Assumptions`, not `$Assumptions$`. Second, when you run `$Assumptions` twice, you override the first cases with `U`. You can make either a `List` of assumptions or connect them with `&&`. Then you'll get `{m,t}` as `TensorDimensions[Y]`.

Comment: `$Assumptions`, per documentation, is only meaningful when used in functions that take the `Assumptions` option. `Dimensions` is not such a function but `TensorDimensions` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have a small typo in `$Assumptions` and this works only with `TensorDimensions`

```
$Assumptions = {U ∈ Matrices[{d, m}, Reals], 
   P ∈ Matrices[{d, t}, Reals]};
Y = Transpose[U].P;
Y // Dimensions
Y // TensorDimensions
```

> {2}
>
> {m, t}